# Getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `post_form' for" when trying to POST data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, post, net-http

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to POST some data to a web site, but I seem to be unable to use Net::HTTP.  I have

```
login_url = 'https://mydomein.com/users/login'
uri = URI login_url
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
resp = http.post_form(uri, fields_hash, headers)
```

but the last line spits out the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `post_form' for #<Net::HTTP mydomein.com:443 open=false>
```

What do I need to do to POST my data?

Comment: Try `resp = http.post(uri, fields_hash, headers)`

Comment: What's the difference?